# Error While Running Android Build On React Native

Tags: android, react-native, cross-platform

I have installed all necessary SDK , Platform Tools . I've the emulator open and running, adb added in PATH. Still this error isn't letting me through.

````
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Launching emulator...
/bin/sh: adb: command not found
info Installing the app...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.flag for more details.


* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:installDebug'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/manndave/IdeaProjects/MyFirstReactNative/android/local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please run the following from terminal, inside the project folder

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/{yourusername}/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
```

Then npm run android

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had running Metro Bundler from another project. Closing it is solved my issue.